# AOP not invoked by annotation

Tags: java, aop, aspectj, pointcut, java-annotations

I am trying to invoke a AOP method for every method that is annotated with @Timed.

My AOP MyTracer.java

```
@Aspect
public class MyTracer {

  private static final Tracer tracer = Tracing.getTracer();
  private static final Logger log = Logger.getLogger(MyTracer.class.getName());

  @Around("@annotation(timed)")
  public Object trackExecutionTime(ProceedingJoinPoint proceedingJoinPoint, Timed timed) throws Throwable {
    String methodName = proceedingJoinPoint.getSignature().getName();
    log.info("Using AOP for method name" + methodName); 
    log.info("Using AOP for param name" + timed.label()); 
    return output;
    }
  }
}
```

My Annotation

Timed.java

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface Timed {
  String label() default "label";
}
```

Finally my business code

HelloWorld.java

```
  @Override
  @Timed(label = "myMetrics")
  public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws IOException {
    log.info("Servlet called");
    PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
    out.println("Hello, world - Flex Servlet");
  }
```

At runtime, I am getting logs from the servlets but not the MyTracer class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The `build.gradle` was missing the following. I replaced

```
compile group: 'org.aspectj', name: 'aspectjtools', version: '1.6.2'
```

with

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "gradle.plugin.aspectj:gradle-aspectj:0.1.6"
  }
}

project.ext {
  aspectjVersion = "1.8.2"
}

apply plugin: "aspectj.gradle"
```

Comment: you can mark it as an answer if it solved your problem